# expect: store output of a spawn command into variable

Tags: bash, variables, command, expect, spawn

Inside my "expect" script:

```
set $REPOS "/path/to/repo/"
set $REV 73
set LOG [spawn svnlook log -r $REV $REPOS]
```

What this will store in the variable "LOG": 16345 (memory location).

What it should store in the variable "LOG": "some message of the svn commit log".

It seems like the is a problem with executing a bash command and then storing that output into an expect variable.

Have you got any ideas? I am new to expect and tcl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did't need spawn there. Try:

```
set LOG [exec svnlook log -r $REV $REPOS]
```

If you really want to use spawn:

```
spawn vnlook log -r $REV $REPOS
expect
set LOG $expect_out(buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exec did the job!

Comment: in the above code what does line no2 means [expect] without any parameters?